# C++ Direct2D Method Advice

Tags: c++, directx, rendering, direct2d

All,

I am trying to draw a cockpit gauge in my program and I'm using D2D to render it. I have started with a filled rectangle and clipped the top and bottom off to create an "artificial horizon" in the shape of the item, which works as desired. However, I now need to draw a white line along PART of the top of the object that is clipped. The clipping rect is below:

```
m_pSink->BeginFigure(D2D1::Point2F((275 * scrScale), (630 * scrScale)), D2D1_FIGURE_BEGIN_FILLED);

m_pSink->AddLine(D2D1::Point2F((275 * scrScale), (750 * scrScale)));
m_pSink->AddLine(D2D1::Point2F((670 * scrScale), (750 * scrScale)));
m_pSink->AddLine(D2D1::Point2F((670 * scrScale), (630 * scrScale)));
m_pSink->AddBezier(D2D1::BezierSegment(
    D2D1::Point2F((570 * scrScale), (790 * scrScale)),
    D2D1::Point2F((375 * scrScale), (790 * scrScale)),
    D2D1::Point2F((275 * scrScale), (630 * scrScale)))
    );

m_pSink->EndFigure(D2D1_FIGURE_END_CLOSED);
```

As I have drawn the curved edge with a bezier, do you know if there is a way to redraw part of that bezier in white? I don't want the whole edge, just a portion at the top. If there is not, can I take suggestions on a better way of drawing it? I have a photo, but can't attach just yet as i'm too new.

Comment: I had thought about using PushLayer and PopLayer to create a mask, and simply redrawing the curve in white and masking out the extent of the curve I needed, but then would it not mask out the rest of the geometry?

Comment: Can you show some pictures please?

Comment: I found a better way of doing it - I used AddArc to create the curved part, that way I have control of the whole arc rather than the system working out the path of the line using the bezier method. Thanks zdd though